# Zend Framework Update Checkboxes in Database

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I have just started with Zend Framework, so might be a bit of a silly question coming up.

I have a Form with 5 Checkboxes. A User can click on as many checkboxes as needed. This gets entered into the Database. (1:n)

This all works fine. But now I am gotten to the part where a User can Edit the Post. The Checkbox gets shown as well as which once are active. But how do I update this now?

The Rest of the Post Update works fine, collecting the Data and send an update:

```
    $this->getDbTable()->update($data, array('post_id = ?' => $id));
```

Now I want to update the Checkboxes, the 1:n Relationship. But how would I do that if I for example had 4 Checkboxes active but after the update I want only 3 active? Should I delete all entries first and than do a normal insert or is there a trick to do it?

Hope someone can help. Thanks !

Comment: I don't think your problem is Zend Framework specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the row existing in your database is what you use to indicate that it should be checked, you will need to delete it as the `update()` function won't do that.

If delete / re-insert is going to be too expensive of an operation, perhaps store the checked values in the session and do an `array_diff($previous_selected, $currently_selected)` to get the list of items to delete.

One thing to note is that the `formCheckbox` view helper by default creates a hidden input with the same name as the checkbox with a value of 0.

Comment: Good, thanks a lot. I assumed this already, but was not sure if ZF provides something which does it automatically.

Since it will ony be a few Checkboxes, I now delete everything with the ID, after that I do an insert.

Works well. Thank you very much !